# Google Geocoding returning wrong destinations

Tags: google-geocoder

I have developed a website that uses Google Geocoding to show distance in miles between point A and point B.
I have performed a great deal of testing and all is working as it should be.
However, whenever my client tests it the destinations returned are not correct.
i.e, I enter postcode EH12 5DR, I correctly receive an address in Edinburgh. When the client tried the same postcode it returned E H Shoes at an address in Belfast. This is only one of a few instances.
This only appears to be an issue with my clients machine and I'm at a loss to explain what is wrong.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Richard

http://www.minibusedinburgh.com/

Comment: have a look at this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755054/google-maps-geocode-showing-wrong-address

Answer (score 0):

Has the client tried in more than one browser ?
Has the client ignored some sort of auto-suggestion - cos it looks suspicious at least, when you have a post code  EH12 5DR and the client gets something back that starts with EH.